# Index out of bound error

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, resultset

Im currently counting and grabbing all the columnNames in a database table  and now im trying to grab every value in those columns by using  values.add(rs.getString(ar.get(i)));
 Though im recieving an index out of bound error and i don't know how to solve it? Any help is appreciated!

```
 for ( i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++ ) {
   ColumnNames = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
   ar.add(ColumnNames);
   System.out.println(ar);   
 }
 model.setColumnCount(columnCount);

 while ( rs.next() ) {
   // values.add(rs.getString(ar.indexOf(i)));
   values.add(rs.getString(ar.get(i)));
   System.out.println(values);

   String value1 = "";
   String value2 = "";
   String value3 = "";
   String value4 = "";

   value1 = rs.getString(1);
   value2 = rs.getString(2);
   value3 = rs.getString(3);
   value4 = rs.getString(4);

   model.addRow(new Object[] {value1,  value2, value3, value4});

}
```

Comment: it cannot be that you let other people do your debugging...

Answer (score 0):

Lists usually start from 0 (rather than 1) so you will always be one ahead (because you start at 1)

if you change your for loop to:

```
for ( i = 0; i < columnCount + 1; i++ )
```

this should work :)

Comment: It's not working. i has to be set to 1 or i get an out of bounds exception [1,4]

Answer (score 0):

Index out of bound mean you are accessing an array index value which doesn't exists for example there is 
int array[] = int[10]; 
If I access array[9] the it will be okay but If I access array[10] then it will gave that error.
So now check your program and debug it.
Here I don't know what columnCount is and also I cannot debug it here